Как узнать язык приложения пользователя, установленного в настройках телеграмма? (aiogram)
а можно вообще замутить такую тему, типа при старте бота, бот должен отправить приветственное сообщение на, допустим, английском, если у юзера в настройках самого телеграма язык - английский, иначе в любом другом языке отвечать на русском? То есть, при каждом вводе команды /start, бот должен отвечать учитывая язык самого телеграма пользователя. Я в интернете наткнулся на language_code (message.from_user.language_code), но не смог ею правильно пользоваться. Язык Python, библиотека/фреймворк aiogram.
# На данный момент мой код выглядит таким образом
@user_router.message(CommandStart())
async def handle_start(message: Message):
    if message.from_user.language_code == "en":
        await message.answer(f"Hello, <b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>!\nFirst, choose a language ", 
                             reply_markup=kb.lang_ikb)
    else:
        await message.answer(f"Привет, <b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>!\nДля начала выберите язык ", 
                             reply_markup=kb.lang_ikb)


Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

@Dev18 Прочитал, думаю я хорошо задал вопрос, так как есть конкретность, "можно или нет?" (да или нет?). Благодарю за напоминание )

Используя message.from_user.language_code, вы можете получить языковой тег (в стандарте IETF) пользователя. Вот примеры тегов.
Затем, применяя оператор равенства, вы сможете определять, на каком языке вы будете давать ответ пользователю. Пример работы вы продемонстрировали в вопросе. Ваш код будет успешно работать, но для того чтобы в полной мере протестировать это, вам придётся изменить язык системы, именно так определяется language_code в Telegram.

В принципе я так и делал. Данный метод работает, но не всегда. Иногда на русском (хотя если сам язык телеграмма стоит английском) и наоборот. Мне надо корректной работы программы)

Отметьте решение как верное, если помог. language_code определяется языком операционной системы, а не языком клиента Telegram.

Ааа вот оно в чем. Получается невозможно, да?

Почему невозможно? Просто язык будет определяться ОС. На возможность локализации это никак не повлияет, а вот во время тестирования будет сложно туда-сюда переключаться.

Понял. Атак Bot API умеет взаимодействовать относительно настройкам телеграмма пользователя?

Вы можете ознакомиться с доступными данными из документации Telegram
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user
